# How do you force WeBlog to reorder blog posts into new folder structure?

Tags: sitecore, weblog

The base WeBlog config contains these nodes:

```xml
<event name="item:saved">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Sharedsource.Tasks.NewsMover, Sitecore.Sharedsource.NewsMover" method="OnItemSaved">
        <database>master</database>
        <templates hint="raw:AddTemplateConfiguration">
            <template id="Modules/WeBlog/BlogEntry" sort="Descending">
                <DateField>Entry Date</DateField>
                <YearTemplate formatString="yyyy">Common/Folder</YearTemplate>
                <MonthTemplate formatString="MMMM">Common/Folder</MonthTemplate>
                <!-- Uncomment the following line if you have too many posts per month (more than 100) -->
                <!--<DayTemplate formatString="dd">Common/Folder</DayTemplate>-->
            </template>
        </templates>
    </handler>
    <!-- Keep the post and comment handlers seperate to ensure comments are structured below posts and not within the same folder structure as posts -->
    <handler type="Sitecore.Sharedsource.Tasks.NewsMover, Sitecore.Sharedsource.NewsMover" method="OnItemSaved" use="comments">
        <database>master</database>
        <templates hint="raw:AddTemplateConfiguration">
            <template id="Modules/WeBlog/BlogComment" sort="Descending">
                <DateField>__created</DateField>
                <YearTemplate formatString="yyyy">Common/Folder</YearTemplate>
                <MonthTemplate formatString="MMMM">Common/Folder</MonthTemplate>
                <!-- Uncomment the following line if you have too many posts per month (more than 100) -->
                <!--<DayTemplate formatString="dd">Common/Folder</DayTemplate>-->
            </template>
        </templates>
    </handler>
    <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Globalization.ItemAndPublishEventHandler, Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog" method="OnItemSaved"/>
</event>
```

If the line below is uncommented for BlogEntries, how do you force WeBlog to reorder the existing blog posts into the correct folders (now containing a day folder)?

```xml
<DayTemplate formatString="dd">Common/Folder</DayTemplate>
```

Currently using Sitecore 7.1 and WeBlog 5.3.

Comment: Saving the item doesn't cause it (which I was assuming based on the the method="OnItemSaved")

Comment: Actually it looks like saving the item again should work. Remember that saving checks whether there is any difference between the original item and new item, so you need to change at least one field before clicking "save".